# GIMME-AWS_CREDS not outputting anything on Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, gimme-aws-creds

I am running a windows 10 with python 3.8.2 with aws cli as 2.9.8. I installed gimme-aws-creds successfully but when i initially ran gimme-aws-creds --version i would get an error "the term 'gimme-aws-creds' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,function, script file, or operable program."

So i found the script file with the gimme-aws-creds package and moved it into my environment variables.

Now when i run any command whether being gimme-aws-creds --version or gimme-aws-creds.cmd. The console just continues to the next line. There is no error or any output info but just goes to the next line.

I feel like i may be missing something in my path because when i run a command now it is no longer giving me an error after moving the python/scripts into the environment variables.

1.I have tried to uninstall gimme-aws-creds however i still run into the same situation
2.I have tried to play around with different environment variables but never have gotten an output from a gimme-aws-creds command